# Searching for time-travel movie set in New Zealand

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I think it's set in Wellington, and the actual travel happens by stepping through a kind of wall --- in one time, in a garage; in another time (I think maybe early 1900's) it's a wall at the back of an alley. And there's a third time as well.

It's a kind of detective story as well: someone gets murdered?

Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Navigator:_A_Medieval_Odyssey? https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2019/02/quirky-sci-fi-farce-mega-time-squad-sends-up-all-those-time-travel-tropes/?

Comment: https://letterboxd.com/film/chronesthesia/?

Comment: If it was set in the UK, I'd have suggested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodnight_Sweetheart_(TV_series) - but if it's set in NZ, I haven't a clue.

Comment: I've seen this movie! You're correct, it is set in Wellington. I recall that it is a bit confusing at the end with all of the twists. I can't remember what it was called... it's probably from around 2008ish.

Answer (score 5):

This movie is "Event 16", released in 2006 and set in Wellington, New Zealand. It is written and directed by Derek Pearson.

The plot involves the MC creating a time machine in his garage and travelling back to a "stylish vision of Victorian Wellington."

The official [website](http://www.event16.com/) hasn't had any [content for some time](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.event16.com/):

Below are a couple of synopses that I found, and their respective sources:

> Masterminded by director and fx whizz Derek Pearson, Event 16 is a brain-teaser spanning three eras. After neglecting his girlfriend (Jocelyn Christian) while struggling to perfect time travel, inventor Matt (Peter Rutherford) inadvertently puts her in danger when a colonial-era killer arrives in modern-day Wellington. Ambitiously plotted, with a plethora of double identities, Event 16 demonstrates how computers have opened new imaginative vistas for the low budget filmmaker — notably in the film's stylish vision of Victorian Wellington.

- https://www.nzonscreen.com/title/event-16-2006

> Matt, a young inventor on the cusp of a breakthrough creation in his garage workshop, is about to lose his girlfriend due to his obsession, when an 1893 cat strolls into the workshop through a wall that his invention created. Soon police, undercover agents and murderers are all hunting for Matt and his girlfriend in a race, not only against, but through time. An independent digital feature from another handful of super-talented Kiwis.

- https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831289/